# How can I use multiple regex expressions with different validation messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, passwords, fluentvalidation

**Requirements**

I want to check password policies by using multiple regex expressions. 
For each policy violation I want to display a specific validation message.

Examples:

- You need to use at least 2 numbers
- You need to use at least one upper and one lower case letter
- You need to use at least 8 letters
- ...

**Attempt**

I tried to use multiple regex expressions (Fluent Validation `Match(string expression)`), but ASP.NET MVC does not allow to have multiple regex expressions.

> The following validation type was seen more than once: regex

**Question**

How can I use multiple regex validators in Fluent Validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom method defined in Abstract validator:

```
public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User> {
   public UserValidator () {
       Custom(user => { 
           Regex r1 = define regex that validates that there are at least 2 numbers
           Regex r2 = define regex for upper and lower case letters
           string message = string.Empty;
           if(!r1.IsMatch(user.password))
           {
               message += "You need to use at least 2 numbers.";
           }
           if(!r2.IsMatch(user.password))
           {
               message += "You need to use at least one upper and one lower case letter.";
           }

           return message != string.Empty;
              ? new ValidationFailure("Password", message )
              : null; 
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this going to translate itself into client side (JS) validation also?

Comment: It is not. If you want client side validation you will have to create a class that generates client side rules. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380010/unobtrusive-client-validation-using-fluentvalidation-and-asp-net-mvc-lessthanore