# How to break a Regex to multiple regex in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a field, I have added a regex for it. So this regex does not allow more than 7 digits before decimal and more than two digits after the decimal. this is working fine, it gives an error message properly. Now I want to give different-2 messages for before decimal points and after decimal points. If the user enters more than 7 digits of a numeric value, then the error message will come under the field as “Maximum 7 digits are allowed.” If the user enters more than 2 digits of the decimal value, then the error message will come under field as “Maximum 2 digits of decimals are allowed.”

```
[RegularExpression("^\\d{0,7}(\\.\\d{0,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter Comment in the right format.")]
public decimal? decimalField { get; set; }
```

**Edit:**
Can we do something line like?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4803634/13211840

If not possible in MVC then how is it possible using javascript or jquery?

Comment: It's not possible in single attribute, you would need to write your own JavaScript code for this.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn can we break the regex into two regex?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it's possible through data annotations. One approach could be, you explicitly validate your model and customize error message based on regex condition in your Action.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("value", "regPattern"))
{
   ModelState.AddModelError("FieldName", "ErrorMessage");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current pattern `^\\d{0,7}(\.\\d{0,2})?$` all parts are optional and will also match an [empty string or a single dot](https://regex101.com/r/TjAPpe/1) as the decimal part accepts between 0 and 2 digits.

If you want to use 2 patterns for 2 different messages, you could match a pattern that allows 1-7 digits before the decimal and 1-2 digits after the dot.

If you want to allow a leading dot without a digit, you could use `\\d{0,7}` instead.

```
^\\d{1,7}(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mfceNQ/1)

---

To match 1 to 7 digits:

```
^\\d{1,7}$
```

Comment: Perhaps this page can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392997/how-can-i-use-multiple-regex-expressions-with-different-validation-messages