# FluentValidation : Compare value with other fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I was referred to using FluentValidation for use in MVC5 C# ASP.NET.  I am trying to compare a field to two other fields but am getting an error.

The code in my customized "AbstractValidator" is the following :

```
RuleFor(x => x.Length).LessThanOrEqualTo(y => y.LengthMax)
   .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(z => z.LengthMin);
```

And when the view tried to render the control for the "Length" field using `EditFor()` this error displays...

> Additional information: Validation type names in unobtrusive client
>   validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was
>   seen more than once: range

How would one go about comparing one value to two other values of the same model.

Answer (score 30):

If you don't mind losing the javascript validation, you can do it using the Must extension of FluentValidation

```
RuleFor(m=> m.Length).Must((model, field) => field >= model.LengthMin && field <= model.LengthMax);
```

HTH

Comment: The **reason** I'm using this is for the JavaScript validation.  Possibly I can just manually add the JavaScript validation myself and use Must.  I'll investigate this option, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet.html#asp-net-mvc-5):

> Note that FluentValidation will also work with ASP.NET MVC's
>   client-side validation, but not all rules are supported. For example,
>   any rules defined using a condition (with When/Unless), custom
>   validators, or calls to Must will not run on the client side. The
>   following validators are supported on the client:
>
> *NotNull/NotEmpty
>   *Matches (regex)
>   *InclusiveBetween (range)
>   *CreditCard
>   *Email
>   *EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
>   *Length

There is some more information to be found regarding rolling your own fluent property validator on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380010/unobtrusive-client-validation-using-fluentvalidation-and-asp-net-mvc-lessthanore).

Comment: I have been looking through the documentation but was hoping someone has already done something similar and could provide a sample. Thanks, I will be look through the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
RuleFor(x => x.Length).LessThanOrEqualTo(x => x.LengthMax)
   .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(x => x.LengthMin);
```