# FluentValidation not working clientside for date comparrison

Tags: date, compare, fluentvalidation

Im using FluentValidation to check if one date is greater than another, heres my rule

```
RuleFor(m => m.EndDate)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End date is required")
            .GreaterThan(m => m.StartDate).WithMessage("End date must after Start date");
```

it works ok server side, but not clientside.  I have other rules and they work ok, this is a required rule

```
 RuleFor(m => m.EmailSubject)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("An email subject is required");
```

I get clientside validation here.  Can anyone tell me where Im going wrong ? It seems pretty ok to me

Comment: the required rule works ok for EndDate, its just GreaterThan that wont

Comment: This one is old, but may still be valid : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380010/unobtrusive-client-validation-using-fluentvalidation-and-asp-net-mvc-lessthanore or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142489/how-to-validate-date-in-clientside-using-fluentvalidation